# Call getMeasuredWidth() or getWidth() for RecyclerView return 0 on data binding

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I'm using data binding to setup a `RecyclerView`. Here is the binding adapter:

```
fun setRecyclerDevices(recyclerView: RecyclerView, items: List<Device>, itemBinder: MultipleTypeItemBinder,
                                   listener: BindableListAdapter.OnClickListener<Device>?) {

        var adapter = recyclerView.adapter as? DevicesBindableAdapter
        if (adapter == null) {
            val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(orientation = SpannedGridLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL,
                    spans = getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth(recyclerView.context, recyclerView))
            recyclerView.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(SpaceItemDecorator(left = 15, top = 15, right = 15, bottom = 15))
            adapter = DevicesBindableAdapter(items, itemBinder)
            adapter.setOnClickListener(listener)
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        } else {
            adapter.setOnClickListener(listener)
            adapter.setItemBinder(itemBinder)
            adapter.setItems(items)
        }
    }
```

`getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth` needs the recycler's width to do some calculation. But it always returns `0`.

I tried to apply a `ViewTreeObserver` like this:

```
recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object: ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

                override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                    recyclerView.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                    val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(orientation = SpannedGridLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL,
                            spans = getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth(recyclerView.context, recyclerView))
                    recyclerView.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
                }
            })
```

Or use `post` like this:

```
recyclerView.post({
                val spannedGridLayoutManager = SpannedGridLayoutManager(orientation = SpannedGridLayoutManager.Orientation.VERTICAL,
                        spans = getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth(recyclerView.context, recyclerView))
                recyclerView.layoutManager = spannedGridLayoutManager
            })
```

Code of getSpanSizeFormScreenWidth:

```
private fun getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth(context: Context, recyclerView: RecyclerView): Int {
        val availableWidth = recyclerView.width.toFloat()
        val px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 300f, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        val margin = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 15f, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        return Math.max(1, Math.floor((availableWidth / (px + margin)).toDouble()).toInt()) * DevicesBindableAdapter.WIDTH_UNIT_VALUE
    }
```

But it still returns `0` despite my `RecyclerView` being displayed on the screen (not `0`).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code for the `getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth` method? Thanks!

Comment: Just added :) didn't put it before as it's nothing special ^^

Answer (score 0):

In inspecting the code, it appears that your `RecyclerView` may actually be fine, but your logic in `getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth` may not be.

It looks like this: `Math.floor((availableWidth / (px + margin)).toDouble()).toInt()` will *always* be 0 when `availableWidth` is less than `(px + margin)`. This will then cause `getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth` to return `0`.

---

Breaking it down:

- `Math.floor` - rounds a `double` **down** to a whole number
- `availableWidth / (px + margin)` - will be a **low** number (a fraction of `availableWidth`)

Therefore, you're going to get `0` at times *especially* on smaller screens and/or smaller density screens.

Does that make sense? May not be this issue, but I'd start there. It's hard to tell you exactly the issue without knowing the whole context, but that's likely your issue.

---

If that is *not* your issue, could you say what your value is for `availableWidth`, `px`, and `margin` during execution?

Comment: But my problem is that with the debugger recycler.width is equal to 0 not the all function :/ so availableWidth = 0, px= 825.0 and margin = 15.0

Comment: Maybe my calculation is wrong for small screen and density you're right, but here I'm testing on a big screen and density so should be right. But thanks I'll take a look for smaller densities when this one is fixed ^^

Comment: Hold on.. I somehow completely missed the `Math.max(1, ...)`. But that means that the last line would **have** to resolve to `<value_1_or_greater> * DevicesBindableAdapter.WIDTH_UNIT_VALUE`. And if you said it's returning `0`, then that means that either `WIDTH_UNIT_VALUE` equals `0` or it is `> 0 and < 0.5` potentially causing it to round down to `0`.

Hopefully that helps. Haha if not, good luck! Hope you get it working..

P.S. this post may have some similar ideas to try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0?rq=1

Comment: No getSpanSizeFromScreenWidth always return 8 because WIDTH_UNIT_VALUE equal 8 :) but that's because my recyclerView.width always return 0 :( I'll keep digging but thanks but your inputs :)